# Align textfields right via jQuery/CSS and within a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops

I want to align the contents of 5 input fields (named "Textfield1" ... "Textfield5") on one page to the right by means of jQuery calling CSS. I tried this:

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
JQuery('#'+ff_getElementByName('"Textfield" + [i]').id).css('text-align', 'right');
}
```

and I tried this:

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
var2 = "Textfield" + [i];
JQuery('#'+ff_getElementByName('var2').id).css('text-align', 'right');
}
```

Neither one works. How to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, what does your html look like?

Comment: The html just assigns the name to an input field. The html is ok because JQuery('#'+ff_getElementByName('Textfield1').id).css('text-align', 'right'); works!!

Comment: Post the `ff_getElementByName` function also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    JQuery('#' + ff_getElementByName("Textfield" + i).id).css('text-align', 'right');
}
```

OR

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var2 = "Textfield" + i;
    JQuery('#' + ff_getElementByName(var2).id).css('text-align', 'right');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Leaving out the '' really is the easiest solution and works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

I think CSS will do this.

```
<input type="text" id="text1" class="align_text"/>
<input type="text" id="text2" class="align_text"/>
<input type="text" id="text3" class="align_text"/>
<input type="text" id="text4" class="align_text"/>
<input type="text" id="text5" class="align_text"/>
<input type="text" id="text6" class="align_text"/>
```

.align_text {
      text-align: right;
   }

Answer (score 2):

The following code works, and here is a link to a demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxKLP/)

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
  fields = "Textfield" + i;
  $('#' + fields).css('text-align', 'right');
}
```

Comment: The OP mentions the elements are `named` "Textfield1" ... "Textfield5", so using `#` may not work.

Comment: You are right and thanks for your answer. Still, a solution has been found even without a concern to ff_getElementByName or #.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('[name^="Textfield"]').css('text-align', 'right');
```

This uses jQuery's [Attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:

```
for (var i=1; i<5; i++)
{
var textfields = "Textfield"+i;
var ids = jQuery("[name="+textfields+"]").attr("id");
JQuery('#'+ids).css('text-align', 'right');
}
```